# SSH tunneling via the router/gateway

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have my router connected to the Internet. From the router, I have an ssh tunnel setup like this:

```
ssh -f tunnelserver.net -L 2000:proxy:8888 -N
```

This opens the port 2000 on localhost from my router. Now I want this port to be accessible from within my LAN, but it is closed. How can I open it?

I have `GatewayPorts yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the interface that ssh should listen to. Something like:

> ssh -f tunnelserver.net -L 192.168.1.1:2000:proxy:8888 -N

or change `192.168.1.1` with the IP assigned on your router's LAN interface.